# Program runs but asks for input twice

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

i have written the following program however every time i run it, the for loops do not work until i enter another number. The for loops then run, using the second number entered. why is this happening? no one seems to be having this problem... here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

float limit;
float count;
float series1, series2;

printf("Enter a limit for the series ");
scanf ("%f", &limit);
while (scanf ("%f", &limit) == 1) 
{
    for (series1 = 1, count = 2; count <= limit; count++)
            series1 += 1.0/count;
            printf ("\nThe sum of the first infinite series is %.4f", series1);
    for (series2 = 1, count = 2; count <= limit; count++)
            series2 += (1.0/count) * pow ((-1),(count - 1));
            printf ("\nThe sum of the second infinite series is %.4f", series2);

        printf("\n\nEnter a limit for the series (q to quit) ");
        scanf ("%f", &limit);
}
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
scanf ("%f", &limit);
while (scanf ("%f", &limit) == 1)
```

The while loop is going to execute that scanf everytime it starts, so just lose the first scanf.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the while loop `while (scanf ("%f", &limit) == 1)` it is running `scanf ("%f", &limit) == 1` again, after you have already ran it. Try setting the first `scanf` to output a variable and run the variable in the while loop.